# JS - Differences or advantages to assigning conditional variables using ||

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements

I've seen Javascript conditional variables written in two different ways. Which is better? Is there any difference? I use the first one because it's shorter but I dont see it used that much.

```
function myFunc(param){
  var test = param || "no parameter"
}
```

vs

```
function myFunc(param){
  var test = param ? param : "no parameter"
}
```

Comment: first is faster, the second allows you to specify an alternative param.
(param?'yes':'no')

Comment: @cocco what do you mean an alternative param? Both of them provide a default value if the param isn't passed in.

Comment: in the first one u pass the param & a fallback value,in the second one u have more options as u can pass 2 custom variables.You can also extend the param (param?param+'blabla':'no param');.Anyway the first one is better if u just need a fallback.

Comment: `||` is a binary operator while `? :` is a ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

In the situation where you might want to do

`var test = param ? "parameter exists" : "no parameter exists"`

That gives you more flexibility than the other method, where

`var test = "parameter exists" || "no parameter exists"`

wouldn't really do anything useful.

Comment: How does it give more flexibility?

Comment: The ternary operator `?` lets you say "If param is true (isn't false or null), then set me to the first option. Otherwise, set me to the second option."  The pipes lets you say "Set me to param if it's true, and "no parameter" if it's not."  It doesn't give you any option to assign test to something else besides param if param is true.

Comment: Therefore include the use of `&&` and the same stuff can be achieved; it's just as flexible

Comment: Can you give me an example of using just `||` or `&&` to achieve the equivalent of `if (param) test = "one"; else test="two";`?  Because with the ternary operator it's just `test = param ? "one" : "two"`.

Comment: It would do something useful though.. it would allow me to set a param if no param is passed in. So I dont get errors later in the code if i'm using that variable